# JPA + Hibernate - One to Many: Get a particular entity only

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have following entity structure:

```
class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aInstance",
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval=true)
    Set<B> bInstances;

    //Other fields and methods
}


class B {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
    private A aInstance;

    @Column(name="b_name")
    private String name;
    //Other fields and methods
}
```

Now, In the DB table, generally, one row corresponding to entity A can have hundreds of B.

But I would be interested in fetching only one such B instance for a given instance of A based on name. For example, I want to fetch A with only B's which has name "XYZ".

How can I do it in one single query?
Or use of two queries (or one native query) is a must?

Comment: What else do you know about `A` that is unique enough to guarantee that you can have one instance of `B`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select b from B b where b.name = 'XYZ' and b.aInstance = :a
```

Comment: That would fetch only B. Maybe I was not clear enough. I want A with only B which has name 'XYZ'.

Comment: You can't do that. f an A has 10 Bs, A.getBs() will always return the 10 Bs. But you can select the Bs you want with their A, which would have the result you want. Just add a `join fetch b.a` to the query.